# Extend cPanel's autoSSL domains list

Tags: linux, devops, cpanel, whm, administration

When I use `autoSSL` function I can see (at `Manage SSL Hosts` page) that ssl sert includes not only my `example.com` domain but also `webmail.example.com`, `cpanel.example.com` and so on but not `whm.example.com`. How can I include `whm` subdomain to this sert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whm service subdomain is only added to reseller accounts.

To get this working the way you want, you'll need to use the Reseller Center to add reseller privileges to the account, and then you can go back and have AutoSSL issue a new cert with the whm subdomain.

> Home »Resellers »Reseller Center

https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/resellers/reseller-center/

In case you're interested in learning more about what service subdomains are the info can be found here. As a side note, the following documentation also makes note that the whm service subdomain only gets a certificate on reseller accounts:

https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/general-systems-administration/service-and-proxy-subdomains/

Comment: Great answer, tnx.